# How to avoid crashing python script when executing faulty SQL query?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am using Python 2.7.6 and MySqldb module. I have a MySQL query that crashes sometimes. It is hard to catch the rootcause for the time being. How can I avoid crashing the python script when executing the SQL query? How can I make it fail gracefully?

The code looks like something;

```
cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Wrap it in a `try except` block: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: To help others help you, post more code.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing"? An error is thrown? Your python process crashed? Someone's computer exploded? Please be more informative :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should throw an exception:

```
try:
   cursor.execute(query)
except mysql.connector.Error:
   """your handling here"""
```

Here is a link to the [MySQL Python Dev guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html):

Answer (score 1):

You can handle run time errors by using `try except` block.

At last you must use **`finally`** for cleanups like **close the connection** , **`rollback`** , free all the used resources etc.

Here is the example ,

```
import mysql.connector
try:
  cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', database='employees')
  cursor = cnx.cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FORM employees")   # Syntax error in query
  cnx.close()
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
finally:
     # cleanup (close the connection, etc...)
```